# Showing that $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, +\infty \}$ is a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ through homeomorphism with $(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

My professor stated that $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, +\infty \}$, **with the induced topology from $[0,1]$** **by any mapping** that is a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, is a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm trying to understand what the meaning of the bold part is precisely. If the homeomoprhism is $h: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then would such a mapping be the following?

$$i: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, +\infty \}$$

\begin{equation}
i(x)=
 \begin{cases} 
      h(x) & x\in (0,1) \\
      -\infty & x=0 \\
      +\infty & x=1 
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

And then, we would state: since $i$ is a homeomorphism, its inverse is continuous, thus inducing a topology on $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, +\infty \}$?

Also - why "any mapping ..."? It seems that, since we need the mapping to induce a topology, we would have to require it to be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially right. What is meant is this:

Take any function $H : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, \infty \}$ such that

1. $H(0) = -\infty, H(1) = \infty$
2. $H((0,1)) = \mathbb R$
3. The restriction $h : (0,1) \stackrel{H}{\to} \mathbb R$ of $H$ is an increasing homeomorphism.

Then $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, \infty \}$ receives a unique topology such that $H$ becomes a homeomorphism (this is true for any *bijection* $H : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, \infty \}$). This topology has the characteristic feature that the subspace topology of $\mathbb R$ inherited from $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, \infty \}$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ (this is not true for an *arbitrary* bijection $H : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, \infty \}$).

You should check that this topology on $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, \infty \}$ does not depend on the choice of $H$; but this is fairly obvious.